# Updating Local Repository of NuGet

Tags: nuget

I  have a local repository of NuGet, but the version of the package "ninject.extensions.conventions" is 2.2.0.5,and I need to Update it to the version 3.0. My current Internet account doesn't allow me to do it in the traditional way(writing "Install-Package ninject.extensions.conventions -Pre" in the Package Manager Console), so I have to use a local repository as I said before. My question is how can I update my local repository counting with the problems of my Internet account

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to download the package manually from NuGet.org (it's just an HTTP GET to the package URL), then install it into your local package repo with `nuget install`.